# Anaconda not installing on mac—conda not found

Tags: python, anaconda

I have an intel 2020 mac and Anaconda will not install into the command line. I have followed the graphical installer directions exactly but whenever I type conda i receive 'command not found.'

How is basic software for data science this hard to install? It is making me want to give up, I have tried everything online including resetting path or whatever. I am a beginner coder and I can't believe such an essential tool is so hard to install?

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes, if you don't restart your terminal after you have installed anaconda also, it gives this error.

Close your terminal window and restart it.

If you're using zsh and it has not been set up to read .bashrc, you need to add the `anaconda` directory to the zsh shell PATH environment variable.

Type:  `export PATH='/Users/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH'`

Then:  `conda init zsh`

Make sure to replace `/username/anaconda` with your actual path.

Save, exit the terminal and then reopen the terminal. `conda` command should work.

Answer (score 4):

- for conda command not found.
- Open Terminal Open bash profile : `sudo vi ~/.bash_profile`
- add this line in bash_profile :

  ```
  export PATH="/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
  ```
- save and quit : `esc + :wq`

  ```
  source ~/.bash_profile
  ```
- Close and reopen the terminal and check `conda --version`